# 1968 I-6 swap questions about the spindles and or any tips/ etc

Tags: engine, ford, mustang, coupe

I have a original inline 6 that I’m swapping with a 302 I already have a c-4 trans that is in the car currently, I know of swapping the front end and what I have to do for the extra weight but (not sure if the spindles on the inline 6 are the same as the v8 originals) planning on doing a 5 lug conversion with disks in the front along with new suspension In the front